# Oracle PLSQL nested cursor for loop issue : Not getting desired results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables Book and Article as follows,

[image]

[image]

I want to replicate all articles for each book as follows,

[image]

but getting some records repeated for bookId 2 (last 3 rows).

[image]

Here is my script. Please suggest alternative solution.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR bookRecords IS SELECT ID FROM BOOK;
  CURSOR articleRecords IS SELECT ID,NAME,BOOK_ID FROM ARTICLE;
BEGIN
  FOR bookRecord IN bookRecords LOOP
    FOR articleRecord IN articleRecords LOOP 
       INSERT INTO ARTICLE (ID,NAME,BOOK_ID) VALUES (ARTICLE_ID_SEQ.nextVal, 
articleRecord.NAME, bookRecord.ID);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM ARTICLE WHERE BOOK_ID IS NULL';
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it just:

```
insert into article
     ( id
     , name
     , book_id )
select article_id_seq.nextval
     , a.name
     , b.id
from   article a cross join book b;
```

That will create a new row in `ARTICLE` for every combination of `ARTICLE` and `BOOK`. I'm not sure what sense it makes to do this but on a technical level that's how you'd do it.

You might also want to exclude combinations that already exist using a `minus` or `not exists` construction.

Comment: AKA A cross join.

Comment: ARTICLE and BOOK are not real entities from Application. They are just describing the scenario from application.  So bookId recently introduced in Article table and every existing article needs to be associated with every book.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use a cursor for this.  Just `cross join`, which combines every row in two tables, exactly like you want.

You can insert as the basis of this statement, but based on the task you are trying to accomplish, I think you ought to insert into a new table rather than your existing article table. As this preserves your existing table that just lists the articles (a useful thing to have, most likely).

```
insert into new_combined_book_article_table (id, name, book_id)
   select row_number() over (order by books.id),articles.name,books.id 
      from books 
      cross join articles
```

Comment: "select row_number() over (),article.name,book.id from book cross join article;" returns error 'ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification'. Also how can I insert rows in article for each book ?

Comment: @Raju, sorry, I'm not an Oracle user--didn't realize an order by statement was mandatory in Oracle.  I have updated the query.  Updated with insert, too.

Comment: Probably `rownum` would do it if you just want a row number.